# How to get post with maximum likes or post with likes counts in rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, join

I am having two models post and like, having a relationship between them. Post has_many likes. I wanted an optimal way to find which post has maximum likes. One way of doing this by

```
count = {}
Post.includes(:likes).each do |post|
  count[post.id] = post.likes.count
end
```

Initially I used array which is not a good data structure so I used hash,but still I am not satisfy with this type of approach.  What would be the best to get posts with likes.

Also, I have tried the following query but it is not working as expected so could anyone can suggest a better and optimal approach.

```
Post.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN Likes ON likes.post_id =posts.id").group("posts.id").order("COUNT(likes.id) DESC")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use `counter_cache`](http://yerb.net/blog/2014/03/13/three-easy-steps-to-using-counter-caches-in-rails/) so that you always have a count of likes on the `Post` objects, then you can call `Post.maximum(:likes_count).first` to retrieve the one post that has the most likes. Likewise, any `Post` query will include a post's like count.

Comment: Nice approach, but since the application is already live with almost 300 posts, I need to write some script to update the existing post right?

Comment: 300 posts isn't very many. You don't have to write a script, typically you would write a rake task (or use `rails c` on production) to run `Post.all.each { |p| Post.reset_counters(p.id, :likes) }` (or whatever your likes association is named). It'll update the count automatically after that.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need joining. Group **likes** by **post_id** and count them. The resulting **post_id** with max count will be id of your most liked post. Then you can join or just select the post you're looking for. In pure SQL it would look like:

```sql
SELECT l.post_id, count(*) as cnt 
    FROM likes l
    GROUP BY l.post_id 
    ORDER BY cnt DESC 
    LIMIT 1;
```